# How to clear or destory memories that is occupied by PHP Object

Tags: php, memory-management

I using PHPExcel reader. Load function reads the Huge Excel and keeps memory until programs ends. This is affecting the program performance down the line.

I would like to clear the memory occupied by php object `$objReader` & `$objPHPExcel` shows in below code.

```
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
            $objReader->setReadFilter( new MyReadFilter($z) );
            $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
            $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
            $objSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
```

`load($inputFileName)` reads the full excel file data & stores it `$objPHPExcel`

Answer (score 5):

I believe you can free up the memory by disconnecting worksheets then unseting the object.

```
$objPHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets();
unset($objPHPExcel);
```